# dimmer switch replacement witing

Tags: wiring

I want to replace a faulty dimmer switch with a new one, but the new switch has 3 wires and the old switch was connected by a yellow wire and a black wire.  How do I connect the red, black and green wires from the new switch to them?

Comment: Thank you so much!  It worked.  I didn't have a ground but wrapped the extra wire like you said.  And thank you for your quick response.

Comment: I am glad it worked any idea why I got a - vote ???

Answer (score 1):

connect the black to black,  connect yellow to red,  green goes to the bare copper that should be in the box if you dont have a ground (bare copper)in the back of your box put a wirenut on the green so it cant find your hot by accident

Comment: Why was this given a downvote? It sounds right...